# Unified Search in WebWorks

Tags: blackberry-webworks

We are trying to get Unified Search to work but I cannont find anything for the WebWorks API and seems to only be available to the Java development environment. Is there a WebWorks Java extension we can use? If not how could we accomplish this within our WebWorks app?

Answer (score 0):

The BlackBerry WebWorks site contains the SearchArguments API to invoke the Search application: https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/apis/blackberry.invoke.searcharguments.html